# How to put error bars into graph in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, errorbar

I'm trying to add error bars to my bar graph, but I keep getting error messages. First time ggplot2 user, any help or explanation is appreciated!

I have used len, mean-sd, se, specific values.. but nothing has worked for me so far.

I have used the following codes:

```
ggplot(data = means, aes(x = hear, y = Mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - Error, ymax = value + Error, 
                    fill = variable))

ggplot(data = means, aes(x = hear, y = Mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = len - sd, ymax = len + sd), 
                width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9))

ggplot(data = means, aes(x = hear, y = Mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = means - sd, ymax = means + sd), 
                width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

And I used this code, but it put the error bars at the bottom of my bars instead of at the tops:

```
ggplot(data = means, aes(x = hear, y = Mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = se, ymax = se), 
                width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

I keep getting error codes such as: the object is not found as well as non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: Please add some sample data and make a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you use `aes(ymin = value - Error, ymax = value + Error, fill = variable)`, you're telling `ggplot` to look for columns in your data named `value`, `Error`, and `variable`. Does your data have those columns? (Also error bars use `color`, not `fill`.)

Comment: If it works, but puts the error bars at the bottom, check the values of `se` against the `Mean`. You may have too small `se` values and therefore go to the bottom of the plot.